# Why don't termcaps work before a `write` syscall?

Tags: c, unix, terminal, termcap

Why is the output of this program not getting underlined

```
int main() {
  tgetent(NULL, getenv("TERM"));
  tputs(tgetstr("us", NULL), 1, &putchar);
  write(1, "Hello world!\n", 13);
  tputs(tgetstr("ue", NULL), 1, &putchar);
}
```

but this **is**?

```
int main() {
  tgetent(NULL, getenv("TERM"));
  tputs(tgetstr("us", NULL), 1, &putchar);
  puts("Hello world!");
  tputs(tgetstr("ue", NULL), 1, &putchar);
}
```

**EDIT**

The issue is, indeed, about buffer management! If I add `fflush`, the string is properly underlined

```
int main() {
  tgetent(NULL, getenv("TERM"));
  tputs(tgetstr("us", NULL), 1, &putchar);
  fflush(stdout);
  write(1, "Hello world!\n", 13);
  tputs(tgetstr("ue", NULL), 1, &putchar);
}
```

Comment: Because termcap/terminfo assumes it is in complete control of the display and the `write()` subverts that.  You'd have to `refresh()` to get the termcap/terminfo information placed.  Then maybe if you're luck the `write()` will work.  But you should not be mixing termcap/terminfo functions with low-level `write()` (or `read()`) functions.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks! But how is `write()` different from "higher-level" functions like `putchar()` and `puts()`? Aside from buffer management?

Comment: Hmmm…I was tempted to say "it's all about buffer management", but that assumes `curses` rather than just `termcap` or `terminfo`.  Then I had nightmares…. Then I looked at the man page (`man 3 tputs` on a Mac) and they are part of `curses` after all — and therefore it is likely that it _is_ all about buffer management.  You've not shown an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).  What else is there in the program?

Comment: The issue was indeed about buffer management! Thanks for your help :)

Comment: `The issue is, indeed` please post that as an answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the difference is that `putchar` and `puts` are *buffered*, while `write` is not.  In this example

```
int main() {
  tgetent(NULL, getenv("TERM"));
  tputs(tgetstr("us", NULL), 1, &putchar);
  write(1, "Hello world!\n", 13);
  tputs(tgetstr("ue", NULL), 1, &putchar);
}
```

the characters written by

```
write(1, "Hello world!\n", 13);
```

are likely to get to the screen first, because (unlike the `tputs` calls) they are written immediately.  The characters written by the `tputs` calls are stored in a buffer (which generally is **much** larger than the strings returned from `tgetstr`), and since you provided no other way to flush the buffer, those are written by the runtime's cleanup as it exits.

Without an explicit return statement, the C standard guarantees that it has the same effect as calling `exit` (which does an `fflush` on each open file—including streams such as *stdout*).

While you could in principle construct a termcap which had extremely long strings, termcap descriptions are supposed to be limited to 1023 bytes (and even terminfo descriptions are generally limited to 4096 bytes), while the standard I/O buffer size is generally several times that limit, so you wouldn't see those `tputs` calls written out without a **lot** of work (i.e., changing the runtime...).